# MAC OS X: zsh: no such file or directory once running a program from Codeblocks

Tags: c, macos, codeblocks, zsh

I am building and running a c program using Codeblocks IDE and this is what I get on the shell:

```
XX@XX-MBP ~ % '/Applications/CodeBlocks.app/Contents/MacOS/cb_console_runner 
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:. /Users/XX/Desktop/Codeblocks/try2/bin/Debug/try2 '
zsh: no such file or directory: 
/Applications/CodeBlocks.app/Contents/MacOS/cb_console_runner 
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:. /Users/XX/Desktop/Codeblocks/try2/bin/Debug/try2
```

however when I run (in the same shell) the following line:

```
/Applications/CodeBlocks.app/Contents/MacOS/cb_console_runner 
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:. /Users/XX/Desktop/Codeblocks/try2/bin/Debug/try2
```

It does work as expected:

```
XX@XX-MBP ~ % '/Applications/CodeBlocks.app/Contents/MacOS/cb_console_runner 
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:. /Users/XX/Desktop/Codeblocks/try2/bin/Debug/try2 '
zsh: no such file or directory: 
/Applications/CodeBlocks.app/Contents/MacOS/cb_console_runner 
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:. /Users/XX/Desktop/Codeblocks/try2/bin/Debug/try2 
XX@XX-MBP ~ % /Applications/CodeBlocks.app/Contents/MacOS/cb_console_runner 
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:. /Users/XX/Desktop/Codeblocks/try2/bin/Debug/try2
Hello world!
```

*How can I solve it so it would run it right away?*

Comment: Could be sandboxing...

Comment: Drop the quotes on the command line. Your script has two separate commands, one with a pre-commend assignment to modify that command's environment. You are trying to run a single command whose name is the entire contents of the file.

Comment: (Or maybe that's one command `cb_console_runner` with two arguments. Either way, those outer `'`s have to go.)

Answer (score 13):

I fix it in this way:
Codeblocks->Setting->Environment setting
Change the option "Terminal to launch console programs" to this:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"' -e 'activate' -e 'do script "$SCRIPT"' -e 'end tell'
```

Regards

Comment: thank you it works. But what's wrong with that bro? Can you elaborate, please? I encounter a lot of problems on this CodeBlocks